# Jira projects showing up to users who shouldn't have permission to see them

Tags: admin, jira

In Jira (4.0), under Global Permissions, I have the Jira Users group containing two groups, jira-users and jira-login. When I started at this company, there was only the jira-users group, but I added jira-login so that I could remove users from jira-users and still have them be able to login. Everyone with jira-users permissions has specific permissions across every project in Jira and I didn't want to have to change that group's access on every project/permissions scheme affected.

Ultimately, what I'm trying to do is have a new group, Suppliers, have limited access to our projects. So a supplier is a member of jira-login and Suppliers only. Regular users are members of both jira-login and jira-users, although since they are a part of jira-users, they can still login without being part of the jira-login group.

The problem I'm having is that suppliers can see the projects that I want them to, but also a few projects that I didn't give them permissions to see. I want to remove the visibility of these unwanted projects for suppliers. NOTE: to let the suppliers see the select projects, I added the Suppliers group the the Users project role on each project that I want them to see.

Under project roles for each of this unwantedly visible projects, the only groups that have access to the Users (or any other project role besides admin) is jira-users. I have no idea how people outside of the jira-users group can see these projects.

I cannot seem to find the common denominator scheme/setting that these suppliers have. Certainly the newly created jira-login group doesn't have any sort of access that I didn't enter in manually. Right?

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by having either "Current Assignee" or "Reporter" in the "Browse Project" permission. Strange behavior. Watch out for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a jira-login and jira user group it might be better to create new groups that don't involve the jura-user group(this might cause odd behavior). From what I have read it seems that all users need to be a part of the Jira-users group to even log in.

Then having permission schemes that only include the groups that you want should be able to lock out unauthorized groups.

Comment: You have to pick one group that everyone belongs to in order to login (under global permissions). Now they are a part of two groups: jira-login and jira-users. I added the jira-login because when I started at this company, the jira-users was being used for all kinds of random permission across all projects and didn't want to change that yet. So now anyone can have EITHER jira-users OR jira-login to log in. So a supplier doesn't have jira-users so that he/she cannot see the permissions my predecessor stupidly associated with that group. A supplier is only a member of jira-login and Suppliers.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to view issues is controlled by the Browse Projects permission. Check the permission scheme for a group that Suppliers can unexpectedly view and see who has that permission. It may be a group or a role. Remove the Suppliers from that and they won't be able to view that project's issues.

More info at http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Managing+Project+Permissions